# Question about modules

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $R^n$ be the external sum of $n$ copies of the $R$-module $R$.  Let's take $t$ elements of our $R$-module $R^n$ and call $M$ the sub-module generated by them. Then call $r$ the maximum number of independent elements among these $t$ elements.  Taking such a subset $S$ of $t$ independent elements, it is not always true that $S$ spans $M$ (it is not always true that $M$ is free over $S$).
If we take as $R$ a PID, then can such an unpleasant situations happen?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, if one takes the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}, n=1$ and $S=\{2,3\}$, the resulting module is $M=\mathbb{Z}$ abd one cannot choose a free basis of $M$ out of elements of $S$. So it is probably quite typical situation.

Comment: @PavelC Thanks!